# validating people picker; allow submit only if all entries are resolved as valid

Tags: 2010, jquery, visual-studio, people-picker

In people picker when I give an invalid id and valid id and click on submit button, both are resolved and list get updated with valid id.

What I need is if I give no values in people picker and submit, the list should get updated with null value and when I give valid and invalid id and submit the list should not get updated with valid id rather it should not allow user to submit by displaying a validation error message " please enter valid id ".

I gave below code but it is not working for me. How can I achieve that.

```
function IsPeoplePickerValueResolved() {

    var eEntityData=$("div[id='divEntityData']");
    if (eEntityData.length > 0)
    {
      var isResolved = eEntityData.attr("isresolved");
      if(isResolved=="True")
        {
            return true;
        }
      else 
        {
            document.getElementById("errorlbl").innerHTML = "Please Enter Valid ID";
            showerrormsg();
            return false;
        }
    }
 }

function showerrormsg() {

    document.getElementById("errorlbl").style.display = "block";
}
```

Iam working in sharepoint 2010 and VisualStudio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to check if there is resolved users or not,

```
var hasResolvedUsers = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.HasResolvedUsers();    
if(hasResolvedUsers==false)
{
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.ShowErrorMessage('Please Enter Valid ID');
}
```

If there’s at least one resolved user in the editor, it’ll return true Otherwise false.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, This code is working for me But i need a slight change like if there is atleast one user unresloved then it should display error message. so i think its good to find a code to select unresolved users. is there any method for that.